# команда python запущенная из cmd не видет модули python. но запускается из IDLE корректно и через

Tags: python, pip, библиотеки, модули, python-3.8

после успешной установки любой библиоткеи :

```
pip install pandas
```

подобный скрипт gg.py:

```
import pandas
```

запущенный из cmd командой:

```
python gg.py
```

сообщает:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gg.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

Но запущенный из IDLE (Run F5):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все успешно работает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же успешно работает и VScode c запуском из Runer.

Powershel так же отказывается видеть модули из скриптов

Системные переменные все стоят и до scripts и до python

Windows10, python3.8.2 - других питонов не стоит, все на чистой системе.

Answer (score 1):

для запуска .py вне IDE используйте командную строку:

```
C:\Users\%username%\%project_folder%\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\%username%\%project_folder%\main.py
```

где `%username%` - имя вашего пользователя в ОС, `%project_folder%` - папка с вашим .py файлом

Answer (score 0):

В Python3 используется команда "py", вместо "python".
То есть нужно написать: py "*путь к файлу (или просто имя файла .py)*"

Comment: Можно и python писать, даже из вопроса видно, что это работает. К тому же вопрос совсем не об этом.

Answer (score 0):

Все решилось!

Если вы пользуетесь inkscape для работы над векторной графикой, то не ставьте галку установить python!

Решение :
Удалить Inkscape, и установить без Python.

```
C:\Windows\system32>python
Python 3.8.2 (default, Apr 9 2020, 13:17:39) [GCC 9.3.0 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
»> import sys
»> sys.path
['', 'C:\\Program Files\\Inkscape\\lib\\python38.zip', 'C:\\Program Files\\Inkscape\\lib\\python3.8', 'C:\\Program Files\\Inkscape\\lib\\python3.8\\lib-dynload', 'C:\\Program Files\\Inkscape\\lib\\python3.8\\site-packages']
»>
```