# Как запустить файл py через бат файл

Tags: python, bat

мне нужно запустить файл py через бат файл , ведь каждый раз писать в командной строке

```
cd Desktop\Python
python 1.py
```

Очень долго я хотел бы просто запускать бат файл и все. я пытался делать так:

```
@echo off
cd Desktop\Python
python 1.py
```

и так:

```
@echo off
echo cd Desktop\Python
echo python 1.py
```

но ниче не работает помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Указывайте абсолютный путь в `cd`, возможно, через переменные среды. Скажем. `cd %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Python`. И учтите, что после `cd` файл `1.py` будет искаться в новой директории...

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1136765/234134 вам требуется указать путь к интерпретатору

Comment: @denzzzy P.S. А может он просто выполняется и закрывается? `print("hello world")` например вы так не сможете посмотреть.

Answer (score 1):

Просто укажите полный путь к скрипту.

```
python C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\asd\test.py
```

Работает даже просто в таком варианте:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\asd\test.py
```

Либо прописывайте директорию относительно местоположения bat файла.

```
python asd\test.py
```

С директорией относительно bat расположенный на рабочем столе

```
cd asd
test.py
```

Все варианты по сути рабочие )

Ну и если предусмотреть все... (полезно для запуска через env)

```
C:\Python\python.exe C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\asd\test.py
```

Comment: последней строкой .bat файла крайне желательно поставить pause или timeout 100 (тогда можно увидеть и прочитать сообщение об ошибке)